# Pylons with Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pylons

According to the pymongo documentation,

```
PyMongo is thread-safe and even provides built-in connection pooling for threaded applications.
```

I normally initiate my mongodb connection like this:

```
import pymongo
db = pymongo.Connection()['mydb']
```

and then I can just use it like db.users.find({'name':..})...

Does this mean that I can actually place that two lines in the lib/apps_global.py like:

```
class Globals(object):

    def __init__(self, config):
        self.cache = CacheManager(**parse_cache_config_options(config))
        import pymongo
        self.db_conn = pymongo.connection()
        self.db = self.db_conn['simplesite']
```

and then in my base controller:

```
class BaseController(WSGIController):

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        """Invoke the Controller"""
        # WSGIController.__call__ dispatches to the Controller method
        # the request is routed to. This routing information is
        # available in environ['pylons.routes_dict']
        ret = WSGIController.__call__(self, environ, start_response)

        # Don't forget to release the thread for mongodb
        app_globals.db_conn.end_request()
        return ret
```

And start calling app_global's db variable throughout my controllers?
I hope it is really that easy.

Answer (score 1):

Ben Bangert, an author of Pylons, has written his blog engine with mongodb. 
You [can browse it's source code online](https://bitbucket.org/bbangert/minger/src).